# zurb foundation Top Bar -> change selected item bg color?

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation, mixins

I'm using latest zurb foundation and wondering how to modify the hover color for the Top Bar component.
I've gone through the available SCSS variables experimenting but can't figure out how to change it.

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/top-bar.html

I've been able to sucessfully change the background color of the bar and set the active color using these variables

```
$topbar-bg: #09243b;
$topbar-link-bg-active: #3c9d20;
```

I'd like to know the following:
* how to change the hover background color
* how to change the hover background color for a topbar dropdown

thanks in advance

Comment: You can override(foundation) this by your own style.

Comment: ? I don't think i follow. can you elaborate?

Comment: .dropdown li:hover{background-color:$your-color;} like this...

Comment: Yes, I'm aware you can override the css class, but I was thinking something so basic would be modifiable via the pre-defined scss variables.